# Stencil Tool seems to be bugged

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

After I got a near perfect UV wrap I got to making the textures. Removed the color grid and brought in an image as stencil. The issue is when I start painting over the stencil, the the projection onto the mesh bugs out and just starts painting smaller versions of the stencil image. Image attached below.

I have tried making a new mesh, using a different image with the same mesh and restarting blender. Nothing seems to work, I can post the .blend file if required

[image: the mesh painting repeated textures]

Answer (score 0):

Welp it seems all I had to do was go to |Texture Properties>Images>Mapping>Extension| and change it from repeat to clip/extend.